# Scala: How to create a loop/conditional statement that allows you to only get the same word to be compared then loop?

Tags: scala

Is there a way to set it so that you can create a loop/conditional statement that allows you to get the word you're looking for and only loop through there?

For example, a csv file:
name, year, language
kyle, 1998, english
kyle, 2011, english
kyle, 1879, french
george, 1978, spanish
zoe, 2000, english

So when looking for kyle, it'll only get the values of kyle and not the other names?

Expected Return:
kyle, 1998, english
kyle, 2011, english
kyle, 1879, french

Sorry if this is simple, but I am new to Scala and not quite sure.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1**: Read the file

```scala
import scala.io.Source
import scala.util.Using

Using(Source.fromFile(filename)) { source =>
  val lines =
    source.getLines()
}
```

**Step 2**: Process each line.
We will parse them into a case class instance and remove any corrupt fields:

```scala
final case class Record(name: String, year: Int, language: String)
object Record {
  def parseLine(line: String): Option[Record] =
    line.split(',').toList match {
      case nameRaw :: yearRaw :: languageRaw :: Nil =>
        yearRaw.trim.toIntOption.map { year =>
           Record(
              name = nameRaw.trim,
              year = year,
              language = languageRaw.trim.toLowerCase
           )
        }

      case _ =>
        None
    }
}

val records =
  lines.flatMap(Record.parsLine)
```

**Step 3**: Filter the records by the predicate you want:

```scala
val namedKyle: Record => Boolean =
  record => record.name.toLowerCase == "kyle"

val validRecords =
  records.filter(namedKyle)
```

**Step 4**: Materialize the results in strict collection like `List`

```scala
val result =
  validRecords.toList
```

**Step 5**: Combine everything together:

```scala
def readValidRecords(filename: String)(predicate: Record => Boolean): Try[List[Record]] =

Using(Source.fromFile(filename)) { source =>
  source
    .getLines()
    .flatMap(Record.parsLine)
    .filter(predicate)
    .toList
}
```